# Showing that the metric space is bounded.

Tags: analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Prove that there exists some $r>0$ so that $d(x,y) \leq r$ for all $x,y \in X$.

A set $E$ is said to be compact if for every open cover of $E$, there exists a finite subcover such that $E$ is a subset of this finite subcover.

My current approach: since $X$ is a metric space, $d(x,y) \geq 0$ with equality if $x=y$. Does this essentially prove that there does exist some $r>0$, which then would lead me to need to prove that $x \neq y$? (Is this where I use the assumption that $X$ is compact?)

Comment: well, i don't think $d(x,y) \ge 0$ proves anything. What can you say about the finite subcovers? whats $\max d(x,y)$ on them?

Comment: I do not really understand your attempt. The classic way to answer this problem is to construct an open cover using open balls, say each having radius $1$. By compactness you only actually need finitely many of these balls to cover $X$. From here, can you show that $E$ has a finite diameter (i.e. there exists $r>0$ such that $d(x,y) \le r$ for any $x,y \in X$)?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872636/how-to-finish-this-proof-about-compact-implies-bounded

Answer (score 0):

Clearly
$$
X\subset \bigcup_{p\in E}B(p,1).
$$
Since $X$ is compact, there exist finitely many $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ such that
$$
X\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B\left(p_i,1\right).
$$
Let $$r=2+\max_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n} d\left(p_i,p_j\right),$$
then if $p,q\in X$, $p\in p_i$ and $q\in p_j$ for some $1\leqslant i\leqslant j\leqslant n$, so that
$$
d(p,q)\leqslant d\left(p,p_i\right)+d\left(p_i,p_j\right)+d\left(p_j,q\right)\leqslant r.
$$
It follow that
$$
X\subset B(p,r)
$$
for any $p\in X$.

Comment: $d(p,q) \leq d(p,p_i) + d(p_i,p_j) + d(p_j,q) \leq r$ Could you elaborate a bit more for this line with 3 terms in the middle? Triangle inequality tells me $d(p,q) \leq d(p,p_i) +d(p_i,q)$.