# Confusion in Understanding Compactness implies boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I was reading the following question : [How to finish this proof about compact implies bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872636/how-to-finish-this-proof-about-compact-implies-bounded) and I have some troubles understanding the proof given by Rene Schipperus

As I see, in the proof we have shown the fact the sequence $x_n$ is not Cauchy. But I don't understand how does this prove that $x_n$ is bounded ?

I can take the sequence $x_n = (-1)^n$, this sequence is Not Cauchy but has convergent subsequence and is clearly bounded.

I am not able to see, how does proving a sequence is not Cauchy  has any effect on the final outcome of the proof ?

Please guide me in this question.

Comment: The proof you reference works by contradiction:  first, the definition of compact is that every sequence has a convergent subsequence.  To show compact implies bounded, it proves that an unbounded set is never compact.  So, take an unbounded set and create a sequence that has no convergent (i.e. no Cauchy) subsequence.  The intent is not show the sequence is unbounded - it is unbounded by definition - but rather to show it cannot have a convergent sub-sequence.  Does that help?

Comment: @WADon: Thank you, that explanation was quite helpful.